# Android Map View Geocoder Syntax

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geocoding

I am a newbie in android.
What I'm trying to do is to get a location by name,
but I can't use this code in my android application.

```
String location = "London";
```

the code below is highlighted by red line saying "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getFromLocationName(String, int) from the type Geocoder"

```
-->>List<Address> addressList = Geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 location="ahmedabad,gujarat,india";

 Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0)
                for (int k = 0; k < addresses.size(); k++) {
                    locationname = addresses.get(k).getAddressLine(0);
                    Log.i("location name", locationname);
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Its A complate Example ANd Also Successfull Running In My Apps...All the Best

Comment: also Define On Header like This...List<Address> addresses = null;

Comment: where does locationname came from?

Comment: sory...But Define String locationname; in Header and String location="etc";

Comment: yes..sure...use this..getLatitude() and getLongitude() inplace of getAddressLine to get Right Geopoint..try it

Comment: do you have any idea how to have multiple response when searching a location. for example I search "Canada, KFC" then it will response all the geopoint of all the KFC located in Canada.

Comment: yes..but use google direction API and Google Place API to easy for u

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceDetails    read this link carefully

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addressList= geo.getFromLocationName("London",10)
```

Comment: get it just need to surround try and catch